# Cannot Convert From String to NewtonSoft.Json.JsonReader

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi, jsonserializer

I am new in Xamarin Forms and I am trying to create a method that requests a list of items from an API. However, I am not able to compile the solution due to the error message

> "Cannot Convert From String to NewtonSoft.Json.JsonReader" in the line
> `var Items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Paises>>(content);`

Here is the entire routine:

```
public static async Task<List<Paises>> GetPaisesActivosAsync()
{
    string baseUri = new BaseUri().baseUri;
    string sufixUri = "/PaisesApi/GetActives";
    var uri = baseUri + sufixUri;

    List<Paises> listaPaisesActivos = null;

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var Items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Paises>>(content);
    }
    return listaPaisesActivos;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

Regards,

Comment: Have a breakpoint at that line and check what's in your "content"

Comment: @Henry What is Paises? "content" is not null?

Comment: Hi @Shaw, the issue is that the error is present in programming time, which does not allow to compile the solution

Comment: Sorry for that. So are you using Newtonsoft.Json, and if so, try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. Plus, recommended using `var` instead of `string`.

Comment: use using System.Text.Json; instead

Answer (score 29):

Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` instead. I was having the same issue on `C#`. The error should disappear after using `JsonConvert` instead of `JsonSerializer`.

Comment: It is all dependent on which library you decide to use. The two choices are System.Text.Json and NewtonSoft.

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

instead of

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Comment: Presumably, they're using NewtonSoft. Asking them to convert to an entirely different serializer without additional instruction isn't especially useful. There may well be benefits to using `System.Text.Json`, but that doesn't answer their specific question about NewtonSoft.

Comment: Note that you can not use both libraries at the same time, since it will give you CS0104 compile error, It would say reference (which is  JsonSerializer in this case) is an ambiguous reference between 'identifier' and 'identifier'. Here is the link for more on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0104?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0104)